# Coq: Error: The reference [Lemma/Theorem] was not found in the current environment

Tags: coq

For some reason I cannot find that lemma defined [here](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Lists.List.html#nth_error_In) and this is driving me crazy.

```
Require Import List.
Require Import Setoid.
Require Import Lists.List.

Search nth_error_In.
```

I get the following error and I can't understand why.

> Error: The reference nth_error_In was not found in the current environment.

What is required to be able to used it.

Comment: What is your version of Coq?

Comment: The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl4 (October 2015) (debian package)
compiled on Oct 22 2015 21:48:26 with OCaml 4.02.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that that theorem is not available on your version of Coq (8.4), only on 8.5. You should either upgrade your version of Coq or back-port the proof in 8.5 to your development.